# if-else statement to increment or decrement inside for loop in python

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, increment, decrement

I will take an input *n* and then print *n* number of lines.Every line i will input a string if this string is "++X" or "X++" then i will add 1 with 0(The initial value of X is 0). If my string is "--X" or "X--" then i will subtract 1 from 0.(If i already take  another string then subtract from this string value).

Here is My code:

```
n = int(input())
c = 0
for x in range(n):
    a = input()
    if a == "X++" or "++X":
        c = c + 1
    elif a == "--X" or "X--":
        c = c - 1

print(c)
```

My input:

```
2
X++
--X
```

My output:

```
2
```

Expected output:

```
0
```

Because,value will 1 for "X++" and 0 again for "--X". So,what is wrong in my code and how can i fix this?

Comment: Your `or` expression for one thing isn't going to work like you may expect. It's basically saying `(a == "X++") or "++X":` which will always evaluate to True in Python. Instead you can do `if a in ('X++', '++X'):`

Comment: You're very welcome =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

The order of precedence in the logic expression makes your expression equivalent to `if (a == "X++") or "++X":`  which will always be `True` because `bool("++X") == True`. Any non-empty string will be True.  So, as other answers suggest, you can use `if a == "X++" or a == "++X":` since `or` is evaluated last in the expression, the interp will evaluate the equality operations first, then apply `or`.

Another more shorthand way to test if a variable has a value that could be a few alternatives is to use the `in` operator.

```
n = int(input())
c = 0
for x in range(n):
    a = input()
    if a in ("X++", "++X"):
        c = c + 1
    elif a in ("--X", "X--"):
        c = c - 1

print(c)
```

So you had a case where a non-empty string evaluated to `True`, there are other interesting cases that evaluate to either `True` or `False` in expressions. For instance, lists:

```
li1 = []
li2 = [1, 2]

if li1:
    print("li1")
if li2:
    print("li2")
```

Will output `li2`.

Bonus round - associating values with string input using a `dict`:

```
>>> def foo(n):
...     d = {'X++': 1, '++X': 1, '--X': -1, 'X--': -1}
...     c = 0
...     for _ in range(n):
...         a = input()
...         c += d.get(a, 0)
...     return c
...     
>>> foo(3)
<-- X++
<-- ++X
<-- ++X
3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
n = int(input())
c = 0
for x in range(n):
    a = input()
    if a == "X++" or a == "++X":
        c = c + 1
    elif a == "--X" or a == "X--":
        c = c - 1

print(c)
```

:)

Answer (score 1):

Change your condition from

```
if a == "X++" or "++X":
```

to

```
if a == "X++" or a == "++X":
```

or

```
if a in ("X++", "++X"):
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to compare with `a` in every second operand of the `or`s. A non-empty string will evaluate to `True`.

```py
n = int(input())
c = 0
for x in range(n):
    a = input()
    if a == "X++" or a == "++X":
        c = c + 1
    elif a == "--X" or a == "X--":
        c = c - 1

print(c)
```